# change network adapter DNS via bat file

Tags: batch-file, dns

some years ago I wrote a small batch script to change DNS addresses automaticly for each network adapter present in the PC. after I wrote the batch script I converted it to exe. 
Meanwhile I lost the code but now I need it again.

I have found the exe file and was able to extract the cmd output:

```
@echo on    
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

    (
    SET adapterName=Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
     REM Removes "Ethernet adapter" from the front of the adapter name
     SET adapterName=!adapterName:~17!
     REM Removes the colon from the end of the adapter name
     SET adapterName=!adapterName:~0,-1!
     netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="!adapterName!" static 8.8.8.8 primary
     netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="!adapterName!" 8.8.4.4 index=2
     netsh interface ipv6 add dnsserver "!adapterName!" 2001:4860:4860::8888
    )


    FOR /F "tokens=* delims=:" %b IN ('IPCONFIG | FIND /I "WIRELESS LAN ADAPTER"') DO (
    SET WadapterName=%b
     REM Removes "Ethernet adapter" from the front of the adapter name
     SET WadapterName=!WadapterName:~21!
     REM Removes the colon from the end of the adapter name
     SET WadapterName=!WadapterName:~0,-1!
     netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="!WadapterName!" static 8.8.8.8 primary
     netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="!WadapterName!" 8.8.4.4 index=2
     netsh interface ipv6 add dnsserver "!WadapterName!" 2001:4860:4860::8888
    )

    ipconfig /flushdns
```

but I have no idea how to make it work again. I totaly forgot to write batch script.

Comment: If you want a HTA for changing DNS ?

Comment: no. In my organization we have about 100 standalone PCs. changing the dns manually will take a lot of time and I want to work less

Comment: On the command line for-loops variables use one `%` but in a batch script you'll have to double it. So you'll have to replace `%b` with `%%b` in your for-loop

Comment: And you'll have to escape the pipe in the for-loop command with a carret: `^|` instead of `|` in the command you loop through